# Theorem 4.10 iii) in the page 204 of Hungerford, applying dual operator to exact sequence

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, exact-sequence

The theorem 4.10 iii) in the page 204 of Hungerford says:

if $R$ is a division ring and $0\rightarrow A\stackrel{\theta}{\rightarrow}B\stackrel{\zeta}{\rightarrow}C\rightarrow 0$ is a short exact sequence of left vector spaces, then    $0\rightarrow C^*\stackrel{\overline{\zeta}}{\rightarrow}B^*\stackrel{\overline{\theta}}{\rightarrow}A^*\rightarrow 0$  is a short exact sequence of right vector spaces where $A^*,B^*$ and $C^*$ denote the dual space. The proof is an exercise, but the suggestion is not clear. I thought of using the theorem 4.6 iii) of page 202

If  $0\rightarrow A\stackrel{\theta}{\rightarrow}B\stackrel{\zeta}{\rightarrow}C\rightarrow 0$ is a short exact sequence of R-modules, then
$0\rightarrow \text{Hom}_R(C,J)\stackrel{\overline{\zeta}}{\rightarrow}\text{Hom}_R(B,J)\stackrel{\overline{\theta}}{\rightarrow}\text{Hom}_R(A,J)\rightarrow 0$ is an exact sequence of abelian groups where J is a injective module.

But then, I need prove that if $R$ is a division ring then $R$ is injective. This is true? How do I prove this or what is the counterexample? What is the strategy by proof the theorem 4.10 iii?

Comment: Sorry for commenting here on this old post. I was reading theorem 4.10 iii. And the suggestion of book is strange as you noted. So I’m confused. I wonder if I can use proposition 4.4 instead of theorem 4.5. My solution is the following. Since R is a division ring, left R-module C is a free module. Then C is projective and the given exact sequence is split. Thus, by proposition 4.4, the induced sequence of Hom sets is split and it is short exact sequence. Am I right?

Answer (score 0):

It is actually easy to show division ring $R$ is injective. Recall characterization of injective $R$-modules in terms of left ideals of the ring $R$.

**lemma 3.8.** (Baer’s criterion) Let $R$ be a ring with identity. A unitary $R$-module $J$ is injective if and only if for every left ideal $L$ of $R$, any $R$-module homomorphism $L\to J$ may be extended to an R-module homomorphism $R\to J$.

Let $L$ be left ideal of $R$ and $g:L\to R$ be $R$-module homomorphism. Since $R$ is division ring, either $L=0$ or $L=R$. If $L=0$, then $f:R\to R$ given by $f(r)=0$ for all $r\in R$. If $L=R$, then $f=g$. Thus $R$ is injective. Now theorem 4.10 (iii) is corollary of theorem 4.6 as you have observed.

---

Comment of user anadad is correct but bit long. I am adding two important result used in anadad’s answer in case readers don’t have copy of Hungerford’s Algebra book.

**Theorem 3.4.** Let $R$ be a ring. The following conditions on an $R$-module $P$ are equivalent.

(i) $P$ is projective;

(ii) every short exact sequence $0\to A\to B\to P\to 0$ is split exact;

(iii) there is a free module $F$ and an $R$-module $K$ such that $F\cong K\oplus P$.

**Proposition 4.4.** The following conditions on modules over a ring R are equivalent.

(i) $0\rightarrow A\stackrel{\varphi}{\rightarrow}B\stackrel{\psi}{\rightarrow}C\rightarrow 0$ is a split exact sequence of $R$-modules;

(ii) $0\rightarrow \text{Hom}_R(D,A)\stackrel{\overline{\varphi}}{\rightarrow} \text{Hom}_R(D,B)\stackrel{\overline{\psi}}{\rightarrow}\text{Hom}_R(D,C)\rightarrow 0$ is a split exact sequence of abelian groups for every $R$-module $D$;

(iii) $0\rightarrow \text{Hom}_R(C,D)\stackrel{\overline{\psi}}{\rightarrow} \text{Hom}_R(B,D)\stackrel{\overline{\varphi}}{\rightarrow}\text{Hom}_R(A,D)\rightarrow 0$ is a split exact sequence of abelian groups for every $R$-module $D$.

Comment: Would be good to mention Lemma 3.8 has a commonly used name (Baer's criterion), too

Comment: @rschwieb I myself didn’t know that.

Comment: [Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Injective_module#Baer's_criterion)